# [34, 105] The expression is not a valid conditional expression

Tags: mysql, sql, jpql

Hi guys i am getting the error :

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT u FROM Appointment U WHERE u.startDatetime BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2 INNER JOIN Users_appointment where u.ATTENDEES_USER_NAME LIKE :search]. 
[34, 105] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
```

when i am trying to run the query

```
public List<Appointment> appointmentRangeSearch(Date startdatetime, Date endDate) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Appointment U WHERE u.startDatetime BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2 INNER JOIN Users_appointment where u.ATTENDEES_USER_NAME LIKE :search");
    q.setParameter("search", "%" + searchString + "%");
    q.setParameter("date1", startdatetime, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
    q.setParameter("date2", endDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

the idea is that i search for a range of dates in the appointment table and then see if there is a matching username in the users_appointment table and if so output this

what is going wrong ?

thanks

Comment: You have 2 WHERE clauses.  Move `WHERE u.startDatetime BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2` to the bottom WHERE clause with an `AND` operation. (fyi: You are probably missing an `ON` clause also)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong SQL syntax used. Please go through the SQL syntax. You need to add a JOINING clause using `ON` to tell mysql how to link appointment table with users_appointment table. I assume that you have userid column in both tables.

```
SELECT u FROM Appointment U INNER JOIN Users_appointment 
ON u.userid = users_appointment.userid
WHERE u.startDatetime BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2
AND u.ATTENDEES_USER_NAME LIKE :search
```

Comment: thanks i have tried that but now get the error `Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT u FROM Appointment U INNER JOIN Users_appointment ON u.userid = users_appointment.useridWHERE u.startDatetime BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2 AND u.ATTENDEES_USER_NAME LIKE :search]. 
[57, 57] An identification variable must be defined for a JOIN expression`

Comment: Not sure but add a space between `userid` and `WHERE`. Currently it is like this `useridWHERE` in your error message

Comment: thanks, but i am still getting the error '[57, 57] An identification variable must be defined for a JOIN expression'